# How to implement searching of a string in an array of dictionaries?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i have an nsmutable array created like this .`

```
NSDictionary *memberInfo = [self.currentChannel infoForMemberWithID:memberID];

    for(int i=0;i<self.currentChannel.memberCount;i++)
    {
        [searchfriendarray addObject:memberInfo];   

    }

     NSLog(@"dfdfdfsear%@",searchfriendarray);
```

The response i am getting is this

```
dfdfdfsear(
        {
        name = baddd;
        status = "<null>";
    },
        {
        name = baddd;
        status = "<null>";
    }
)
```

`
Now i want to search an nsstring in this.with the method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Can anybody help me in implementing the search and load my tableview according to that?

Comment: If I tell you that you can create a set of dictionaries with `NSMutableSet +setWithArray:` and then search through any  key's values using `NSMutableSet -filterUsingPredicate:` and the predicate created with `NSPredicate +predicateWithFormat`, will you have any problem to implement it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to filter the array.

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchString];
[yourMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Comment: it will be great if u code according to my arraynames..i need to loopthrough my array and update my array according to that.

Comment: Are you so lazy that you don't want to replace an array name?

Comment: @bugfinder Assuming you were specialized at Android development, there're a few hints. `NSMutableArray  -filterUsingPredicate` will not change the receiver state but will return the result as the new `NSMutableArray *`. You'll want to do `arrayToSearchAt = [arrayToSearchAt filterUsingPredicate:...]` where `arrayToSearchAt` is `NSMutableArray` instance. That is important to understand that unlike Java, Objective C statement `(NSMutableArray*)arrayToSearchAt` doesn't do type casting, if you have `NSArray *` you'll want to use first `NSMutableArray +arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)`

Comment: @bugfinder but doing what you asked is a bad idea as you'll not be able to undo search if you always change the original datasource (sorry, I didn't manage to fit one comment length limitation). Instead you can keep the original array unfiltered and store the filtering results in a separate array which will be used to display the data. Then you always can 'undo' the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) for this.

**Predicate**
**A predicate is a useful object that filters an array. It’s a bit like having a select with a simple where clause in SQL.**

If you have array in this format

```
NSMutableArray *yourAry;
(
        {
        category = classic;
        quote = "Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn.";
        source = "Gone With the Wind";
    },
        {
        category = classic;
        quote = "Here's looking at you, kid.";
        source = Casablanca;
    }
{
        category = modern;
        quote = "I solemnly swear that I am up to no good.";
        source = "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban";
    },
        {
        category = modern;
        quote = "You like pain? Try wearing a corset.";
        source = "Pirates of the Caribbean";
    }
)
```

And you want to search all the array which `category = classic` then we can use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html).

```
NSString *selectedCategory = @"classic";

   //filter array by category using predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", selectedCategory];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.movieQuotes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Follow this blog if you need any help [MyBlog](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/10/predicates.html)