# Using NSMutableArray get object?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have JSON like this:

```
[{
"username":"bitu","password":"123456", "id":"1"
},
{
"username":"admin","password":"admin", "id":"2"
},
{
"username":"demo","password":"demo", "id":"3"
},
{
"username":"admin","password":"admin", "id":"8"
},
{
"username":"admin","password":"admin", "id":"5"
}]
```

I want to use `NSMutableArray` for get `"id"`. How I can do it?
Help me, please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927880/how-to-implement-searching-of-a-string-in-an-array-of-dictionaries/12929788#12929788

Comment: follow my answer...use predicate...and use SBJSON classes to parse json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let NSArray *info array contains your data. Here I am going to retrive your data and save it in NSMutableArray name, password and id.

Initailise these arrays at viewDidLoad methods as

```
   NSMutableArray name=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
   NSMutableArray password=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
   NSMutableArray id=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Use following code after retriving JSON response

```
   NSArray *info;  // this array contains your data
   int counter=[info count];

   for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
   {
         NSDictionary *currentObject=[info objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *userName=[currentObject objectForKey:@"username"];
         NSString *userPassword=[currentObject objectForKey:@"password"];
         NSString *userID=[currentObject objectForKey:@"id"];
         [name addObject:userName];
         [password addObject:userPassword];
         [id addObject: userID];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[yourArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"id"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Value with `objectAtIndex` and  `valueForKey` from `NSMutableArray`

```
NSString *UserName = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"username"];//if you required
NSString *Password = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"password"];//if you required
NSString *UID = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"id"];
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *obj in yourJsonArray) {
        [idArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }
NSLog(@"%@",idArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example, Array have string objects.

```
Acccess:
NSString.FromHandle(deviceList.ValueAt(i));
```